# Can I filter a RSS stream for a keyword and if found, hide the stream on website?

Tags: javascript

I was looking this up but couldn't find this question before. I have a RSS stream on my website which shows weather alerts. In case there are no alerts it says : "No alerts in effect"

Is it possible to filter this with a JavaScript and if found hide that script on the website?

Here is the stream and how its displayed on the website. I basically pasted this in the website code.

I am not really into JavaScript, just start to learn it and it seems a little difficult.

`<div align="center"> <rssapp-list id="e9zUmczW5YQD4WEP"></rssapp-list><script src="https://widget.rss.app/v1/list.js" type="text/javascript" async></script> </div>`

So that result of the stream is shown perfectly in place. I Just would like to hide it when there are no active alerts.

Comment: The output that script creates gets encapsulated in Shadow DOM, so most likely it will _not_ be possible for you to interact with that content using your own client-side scripting.

Comment: @CBroe Would it be possible with this one?

    [link](https://rss.app/feeds/e9zUmczW5YQD4WEP.xml) _italic_ **bold**

Comment: @evolutionxbox could you give me a hint? I'm just starting with JavaScript and find it e bit complex...

Comment: `https://rss.app/feeds/e9zUmczW5YQD4WEP.xml` appears to be CORS-enabled, so yes, you can fetch that resource using client-side JavaScript. But you will have create an HTML display out of the XML data yourself then.

Comment: @CBroe That's fine I can do that. Just the parsing seems to be pretty difficult and  I was hoping I could learn something